# How do I add function which returns 3 numbers, not just 1

Tags: c++, function

My program calculates the square of triangles entered by user using formula S = 0.5 * a * b * sin(A)(A is angle between a and b). The program does it right, but I wonder how to add new function and then call it inside the for loop. The function I want to create should contain these 2 lines of code. The problem is that I don't know how to write a function that returns several values, not just one.

```
cout<<"Enter triangle"<<endl; 
cin>>a>>b>>angle;
```

The source code of program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double calc(double A, double B, double Angle);      
void printResults(double square, double max_square);

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    double a, b, angle, square, max_square = 0; 

    cout<<"How many triangles do you want to enter?"<<endl;
    cin>> n;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter triangle"<<endl; // so I want to call my own function here
        cin>>a>>b>>angle;             // the body of function should contain these 2 lines

        square = calc(a,b,angle);   
        if (square > max_square)     
            max_square = square;
        printResults(square, max_square);
    }
    return 0;
}
double calc(double A, double B, double Angle)
{
double s, s_max = 0;
s = 0.5 * A * B * sin(Angle);
return s;
}
void printResults(double square, double max_square) 
{
    cout<<"------------------------\nCurrent square is"<<square<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum square is"<<max_square<<"\n------------------------\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: that `/` should be `{`

Comment: The same way you added the `calc` and `printResults` functions. What's the problem?

Comment: In your question you said you want to replace the code that asks for `n`. But the comments in the program say you want to replace the code that asks for `a`, `b`, and `angle`. Which is it?

Comment: Is your question about how to write a function that returns 3 numbers, not just 1? Use pointer or reference parameters.

Comment: @Barmar, the problem is how to get the parameters from the function I want to create?

Comment: @Barmar, that was my inattention

Comment: You don't get parameters _from_ a function, you pass them _to_ a function and you get the return value from it. Please clarify what you're asking and what you're trying to do. "How do I add new functions in my program?" is incredibly vague.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, my question about how to write a function that returns 3 numbers, not just 1? But I don't know how to use pointers in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reference parameters:

```
void readTriangle(double &param_a, double &param_b, double &param_angle) {
    cout<<"Enter triangle"<<endl;
    cin>>param_a>>param_b>>param_angle;
}
```

Then your loop can use:

```
readTriangle(a, b, angle);
```

You can also do it using pointers:

```
void readTriangle(double *a_ptr, double *b_ptr, double *angle_ptr) {
    cout<<"Enter triangle"<<endl;
    cin>>*a_ptr>>*b_ptr>>&angle_ptr;
}
```

and you call it as:

```
readTriangle(&a, &b, &angle);
```

The second version is a little more verbose, but it makes it clearer that the arguments are intended to be overwritten.